# Struts2 - How to find errors found during xml validation in the validate method?

Tags: struts2, struts

I believe that if both - **xml validation**, and **validation in the action class** are setup, then, irrespective of whether errors were discovered in the xml validation phase, the action class' `validate` method will be called. Building on this premise, how can I know that there were any xml validation errors from inside my action's `validate()` method (`getActionErrors().size() == 0`.. something like that).

My purpose is to set certain variables of the action class if there were validation errors before sending control back to the jsp. (setting them inside `prepare` would be wrong, as prepare would execute irrespective of whether there were errors)

Comment: `getActionErrors().size()` will return something greater than 0 if there are some errors I guess.

Comment: @Pigueiras - getFieldErrors().size() would also return the errors, I guess.. what's the difference b/w the 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this. If there is any error related with the field that you declared in the xml, with the method `hasFieldErrors()` you will solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getFieldErrors()`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getFieldErrors%28%29) which returns

> Map with errors mapped from fieldname (String) to Collection of String
>   error messages

There are also helper methods such as [`hasActionErrors()`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#hasActionErrors%28%29) and [`hasFieldErrors()`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#hasFieldErrors%28%29) which will help you determine if errors already exist.

Note that the first tells you if there are Action-level errors and the latter helps determine if there are specific, field associated errors.